# Drupal - Template for Custom Page

Tags: drupal, templates

I've got a custom page I created programmatically using hook_menu.  I can have it return content without a problem.  However, I want it to appear within the content region of my page.tpl.php template so that blocks can be incorporated in the page.  Same way that Views allows you to give a view a custom url while still appearing in the page.tpl.php template.

How do I do this for my page?  By default, I just get a with only my content.

Thanks,
Howie

Comment: Can you paste the code you used to create your page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page callback function, if you just print the content of your page without returning anything, it won't be included within your page.tpl.php.  If you return a string containing the contents of your page, it will go into the content region, i.e.

```
function mymodule_page_callback () {
   $content = "Hello, world inside the content region";
   return $content;
}
```

Comment: You want to call me a moron publicly or via a private message?  Of course it was that easy. - thanks.

Comment: @Ward, you'll hear no name calling from me.  It's not that well documented.  Believe me, I know.  I recently pulled my hair out trying to do the opposite (for ajax purposes).

Comment: YES! Agree with Karl that there is some hair pulling when it comes to ajax, and it's not documented clearly.

Comment: okay, now I feel better.  I just have to remember return vs print and I'm good.